# Java JTextField empty string error

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield

I keep getting an error for empty string as you can see below

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

I am unsure why I keep getting this error since I do not try to calculate without typing a number within the JTextField. Below is the code I am using for the calculate button which is fairly simple.

```
private void ButtonCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
         Height = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldHeight.getText());
         Weight = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldWeight.getText());
         BMI = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldBMI.getText());
         answer = Height + Weight;
        this.TextFieldBMI.setText("The answer is: " + answer);
    }
```

These are the defined variables

```
//variables
    static int Height;
    static int Weight;
    static int BMI;
    static int answer;
```

Comment: thats not true, I am entering a digit inside the JTextfields then I am hitting the Button to calculate and I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further help. What you are showing doesn't paint a clear enough picture to help you solve your problem

Comment: this.TextFieldHeight.getText() makes my head spin. Are you in a class hierarchy containing TextFieldHeight, TextFieldWeight and TextFieldBMI and use static getText method that is overriden at each step?

Comment: Sorry I apologize! I added the BMI variable when I shouldnt have since an answer is suppose to be outputted into the TextFieldBMI rather than .getText() from it so it was always empty. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I apologize! I added the BMI variable when I shouldn't have since an answer is suppose to be outputted into the `TextFieldBMI` rather than `.getText()` from it so it was always empty. Problem solved!

Comment: So simple. Someone should have spotted that. But please for future reference, when you post a question, include a short runnable example that demonstrates the problem (that we can copy-paste-compile-run)

Comment: I will do that for all future questions, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are clicking on button while one of your textfields is empty `""` you should add `empty` check before going for parsing.

```
     if(!TextFieldHeight.getText().trim().equals("") && 
        !TextFieldWeight.getText().trim().equals("") && 
        !TextFieldBMI.getText().trim().equals("")){
      //Parse string
     }
```

*Note: As per naming convention variable names should start with small case.*

You may also face the exception when you enter some String which can not be parsed to integer.

Comment: _"I am unsure why I keep getting this error since I do not try to calculate without typing a number"_ - Don't really see how this would make a difference, given the OP's statement is true. Maybe a referencing problem or the OP typing in illegal characters. Hard to tell without an MCVE

Comment: This is a good solution, but it will only work if the string is empty. NumberFormatExceptions can happen for manyreasons, e.g. the string contains letters.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the TextField is empty (getText() returns ""), so the Integer class can't parse anything and throws an exception instead. You should sourround the parsing code with `try/catch`:

```
try{
    Height = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldHeight.getText());
    Weight = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldWeight.getText());
    BMI = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldBMI.getText());
    answer = Height + Weight;
    this.TextFieldBMI.setText("The answer is: " + answer);
catch(NumberFormatEeceptinon e){
    //So something when paring failed, e.g. show a error message
}
```

Comment: Solves the exception going wild and is an overall good practice, but does not address the real problem of the field being empty when it's supposed to be

Comment: Sure, but from what OP has posted, this is the only thing i can do for now. The problem that the string is empty lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Deltharis sorry I should realy start reading more carefully :/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you keep TextFieldBMI empty when you press the jButton which you want to print the answer in! You should comment the line in the code shown below. If you want enter new BMI value  you need to create another textfield for it and for the answer create another textfield as well . If you keep the TextFieldBMI empty with your original code , and press the button you will get the same error again.

[image]

**Commented Your Code and it is working ;**

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

         Height = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldHeight.getText());
         Weight = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldWeight.getText());
//       BMI = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldBMI.getText());
         answer = Height + Weight;
        this.TextFieldBMI.setText("The answer is: " + answer);



    }
```

**If you want to calculate BMI ;**

[image]

**Your Fields Should be ;**

```
    static int Height;
    static int Weight;
    static double BMI;
    static int answer;
```

**Your Button Action Should be;**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        Height = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldHeight.getText());
        Weight = Integer.parseInt(this.TextFieldWeight.getText());
        BMI = getBMI(Weight, Height);
        this.TextFieldBMI.setText("BMI is  " + BMI);


    }
```

**BMI Calculation Method Should Be ;**

```
private static double getBMI(int weightInKg, int heightInCm) { 

    return weightInKg / Math.pow(((double) heightInCm / 100), 2); 
}
```